# Why can I not access my fonts in rails app for Hoefler Frere Jones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fonts, assets

I am trying to access a fonts folder in my site in production.

I am using Hoefler Frere Jones fonts and it basically asks to add the fonts into the site. It keeps giving me a not found error when I try to access the /fonts/165137 folder but when I type in /fonts/165137/1D3CD1EB968865CCC.css I can see the file.

I wondered what the correct way is to do this for rails?

All I basically need to do is add the fonts to my site and make the sub folders accessible in them so they can be found when moving the sites fonts to production but I keep getting 403 errors.

Can anyone suggest what the issue is?

Comment: Can you show us your CSS files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I try to access the /fonts/165137 folder

/fonts/165137 - is a directory and probably directory listing is disabled by your webserver that's why you're getting the error. And check paths to the font-files from the css-file.